# JavaScript - Replace variable from string in all occurrences

Tags: javascript, replace

OK, I know if I have say the character '-' and I want to remove it in all places in a string with JavaScript, I simply ...

```
someWord = someWord.replace(/-/g, '');
```

But, when applying this to an array of characters, it s not working ...

```
  const badChars = ('\/:*?"<>|').split('');
  let fileName = title.replace(/ /g, '-').toLocaleLowerCase();
  for (let item = 0; item < badChars.length; item++) {
    // below will not work with global '/ /g'
    fileName = fileName.replace(/badChars[item]/g, '');
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could build a regular expression instead of using a string of characters... something like `const badChars = /[\/:*?"<>|]/g;`

Comment: @JamesAllardice—that's what the OP **thinks** is happening, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ....

```
   fileName = fileName.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

`/badChars[item]/g` looks for `badChars`, literally, followed by an `i`, `t`, `e`, or `m`.

If you're trying to use the character `badChars[item]`, you'll need to use the `RegExp` constructor, and you'll need to escape any regex-specific characters.

Escaping a regular expression [has already been well-covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript). So using that:

```
fileName = fileName.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.quote(badChars[item]), 'g'), '');
```

**But**, you really don't want that. You just want a character class:

```
let fileName = title.replace(/[\/:*?"<>|]/g, '-').toLocaleLowerCase();
```